# About the ORDER BY - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get all last user's chats with other users:

These are my tables:

**Tabled called "user_data"**

```
---------------------------
| id | owner |    name    |
---------------------------  
|  1 |  120  |  "Nicolas" |   
|  2 |  140  |   "Angel"  |
|  3 |  200  |   "Isaac"  |
---------------------------
```

**Table called "private_messages"**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | ownerID | toUserID | chatID | message             | date        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |   120   |   140    |   10   | "Hi"                | 1489777023  |
|  2 |   120   |   140    |   10   | "How are you?"      | 1489777024  |
|  3 |   120   |   140    |   10   | "I miss u"          | 1489777025  |
|  4 |   140   |   120    |   10   | "Viewed."           | 1489777123  |
|  5 |   200   |   120    |   20   | "Hey! What happen?" | 1489777111  |
|  6 |   200   |   120    |   20   | "We were friends."  | 1489777300  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want getting the last message of each chat of the current logged in user. So, I make the next one: First I get all chats where my ID is the same that the "ownerID" and "toUserID", then I agroup these data with the "chatID".

My query:

```
SELECT
    _d.chatID, 
    ANY_VALUE( _d.name) AS name,
    ANY_VALUE( _d.message) AS message,
    ANY_VALUE( _d.date) AS date 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        user_data.name,
        private_messages.message,
        private_messages.date,
        private_messages.chatID 
        FROM private_messages 

        INNER JOIN user_data ON private_messages.owner = user_data.owner 

        WHERE private_messages.owner = "120" 
              OR private_messages.touser = "120"

        ORDER BY private_messages.date DESC) AS _d
GROUP BY _d.chatID
```

The problem is this shows me the first message and not the last, for example, this query give me the next data:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| name      | message               | date        |
---------------------------------------------------
| "Nicolas" |   "Hi"                | 1489777023  | <-- First message
| "Isaac"   |   "Hey! What happen?" | 1489777111  | <-- First message
---------------------------------------------------
```

I desire this result:

```
------------------------------------------------
| name    | message              | date        |
------------------------------------------------
| "Angel" |  "Viewed."           | 1489777123  | <-- Last message
| "Isaac" |  "We were friends."  | 1489777300  | <-- Last message
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If `private_messages.id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` you can use this:

```
select m.chatID, ud.name, pm.message, pm.date
from (
    select max(id) as id
    from private_messages
    where 120 in (ownerID, touserID)
    group by chatID
) sub
join private_messages pm on pm.id = sub.id
join user_data ud on ud.owner = pm.owner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.name,
       A.message,
       A.date1
  FROM     
 ( 
 SELECT MAX( _d.ownerID ) AS ownerID, MAX( _d.message ) AS message,MAX( _d.date1 ) AS date1
    FROM 
       (
         SELECT                
                private_messages.ownerID,
                private_messages.message,
                private_messages.date1,
                private_messages.chatID 
           FROM private_messages 
        INNER JOIN
                user_data
             ON private_messages.ownerid = user_data.owner1 
          WHERE private_messages.ownerid = 120
             OR private_messages.touserid = 120
       ORDER BY private_messages.date1 DESC
       ) AS _d
GROUP BY _d.chatID
) A
INNER JOIN 
user_data B
ON A.ownerID = B.owner1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you select only the chatID and date and group by chat id:

```
select chatID, max(date) as maxdate
from private_messages
where ownerID = 120
or toUserID = 120
group by chatID
```

the interim result will be

```
chatID    maxdate
------    -------
10        1489777123
20        1489777300
```

Join this result then with the two other tables you have to get your disired result.
(`maxdate = date`)

Note that `select max(date)` / `group by chatID` must be done first to get rid of the `ANY_VALUE` construct which you can not predict what value is chosen from.